# How to get data from an opc server using python?

Tags: python, opc, opc-ua

I have an opc server, and what I am looking to do is get/read data from my OPC server from python, is this possible?

I found this documentation where they use the OpenOPC library:

**Link:**
http://openopc.sourceforge.net/

Is this the correct way to do it?

My main objective is to obtain the data from the OPC server and then send it to a database, I have already done writing to the database.